# ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allows for this column - How do i get which column it is referring to?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Do we have any standard oracle error tables or anything to identify which column in a table i have entered a value larger than specified precision.

`ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allows for this column` - How do i get which column it is referring to?

Comment: good question, The best i can think is doing a select and cast each field to the proper type as target table.

Comment: So how many columns you are updating or inserting into which are decimal type

Comment: The full error consists of several parts: message, context and additional information. The column is part of the additional information and not of the message itself. Make sure you use a tool that gives you the full error, not just the message, when you run the SQL statement.

Comment: I have to correct myself. The column name is not part of the error. But the line and column number of the error should point exactly at the problematic expression within the query.

Comment: @mihai: I have around 12 columns of decimal types in insert statement.

Comment: Sometimes. Binary search, modify the the statement to only apply to half. (For not null change to known good.) If still errors, then half of the half. If not, then half of the other half.

Comment: where ever i looked for the solution, i see it as a manual process, didn't oracle thought of it and stored it somewhere as oracle know while modifying or inserting the value in table, which column and what value it is inserting.. it would have been rather helpful.

Comment: My usual approach for this sort of problem is to implement some sort of debug output which will print the length of each column before the insert/update is run - then compare these with the maximum lengths of the columns in the table.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to write a procedure and try to update the column one by one.

Let's say you have an update like this:

```
UPDATE TABLE_1 a SET (COL_1, COL_2, COL_3) = 
   (SELECT COL_1, COL_2, COL_3 FROM TABLE_2 b WHERE a.COL_ID = b.COL_ID);
```

Then you can loop over all columns by this:

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR TabColumns IS 
    SELECT column_id, column_name, data_precision, data_scale
    FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS 
    WHERE table_name = 'TABLE_2'
       AND column_name <> 'COL_ID'
    ORDER BY 1;

BEGIN
    FOR aCol IN TabColumns LOOP
    BEGIN 
        sqlstr := 
            'UPDATE TABLE_1 a SET '||aCol.column_name ||' = '
                ||' (SELECT '||aCol.column_name ||
                ||' FROM TABLE_2 b '
                ||' WHERE  a.COL_ID = b.COL_ID)'

            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlstr USING CalcDate, CalcDate;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'Error at column '|| aCol.column_id||CHR(9)|| aCol.column_name||CHR(9)||SQLERRM);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( sqlstr );
    END;
    END LOOP;

END;
```

Not very efficient you should see the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing an INSERT, create a view based on the query or values (SELECT FROM DUAL) you're inserting. Then DIFF the view with the table you're inserting into. You ought to be able to find where the data types do not match in size/precision/scale.