# Error in executing plsql procedure (value larger than specified precision allowed for this column)

Tags: plsql

Here is my procedure where i want to insert values with the conditions like emp id start with sequence 131, phone number must be 13 digits, hire date not greater than sys date and salary not greater than 50,000. while executing im facing error . how to solve this.

```
create or replace procedure empinsert AS

cursor employee is select length(PHONE_NUMBER),HIRE_DATE,SAL  from emp;

e_mobile_no emp.phone_number%type;
e_hire_date emp.hire_date%type;
e_salary emp.sal%type;
Begin
 open employee ;
 loop
 fetch employee into e_mobile_no,e_hire_date,e_salary;
    if ( e_mobile_no = 13 and e_hire_date < sysdate and e_salary <=50000 ) then 
INSERT INTO EMP (EMP_ID,
                     EMP_NAME,
                     EMAIL,
                     PHONE_NUMBER,
                     HIRE_DATE,
                     JOB_ID,
                     SAL)
                     values(empinc.nextval, 'ramji','ramji@gmail.com','8975432109875','10/07/2021','JUN_TECH',40000);
                     else
                   exit;
end if;
end loop;

end;
/
```

Comment: Who knows; at least one value you're inserting doesn't fit. You should have posted table description as well. Also, if HIRE_DATE's datatype is DATE, don't insert a string into it (and rely on implicit datatype conversion).

Comment: Please see [Capture the column causing ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57387307)

Comment: What error are you getting? Your question doesn't contain any Oracle error